# How to add effect on jQuery method "addClass"?

Tags: jquery

I have made a slideshow by `addClass` and `removeClass`, but there are  no effects for slider. So I want to add some effects on the method `addClass` and `removeClass`.

```
$('#button-next').on('click', function () {
    $('#big img').css({
        'display': 'none'
    });

    var currentActiveImage = $('.image-shown');
    var nextActiveImage = currentActiveImage.next();

    if (nextActiveImage.length == 0) {
        nextActiveImage = $('.carousel-inner img').first();
    }

    currentActiveImage.removeClass('image-shown').addClass('image-hidden').css({
        'z-index': '-10'
    });
    nextActiveImage.addClass('image-shown').removeClass('image-hidden').css({
        'z-index': '2000'
    });
    $('.carousel-inner img').not([currentActiveImage, nextActiveImage]).css('z-index', 1);
    e.preventDefault()
});

$('#button-prev').on('click', function () {
    var currentActiveImage = $('.image-shown');
    var nextActiveImage = currentActiveImage.prev();
    if (nextActiveImage.length == 0) {
        nextActiveImage = $('.carousel-inner img').last();
    }
    currentActiveImage.removeClass('image-shown').addClass('image-hidden').css({
        'z-index': '-10'
    });
    nextActiveImage.addClass('image-shown').removeClass('image-hidden').css({
        'z-index': '2000'
    });
    $('.carousel-inner img').not([currentActiveImage, nextActiveImage]).css('z-index', 1);
    e.preventDefault()
});
```

Comment: Can you give a JSFiddle link?

Comment: Are you trying to add effects using `addClass` and `removeClass` of jQueryUI? Did you import it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS3 animation features.

[CSS3 animations](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp)

Comment: If you post an answer, please explain thoroughly, ideally with some code and an example. Do NOT just post a link.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use CSS transitions.

Add `opacity: 0;` CSS property to `.image-hidden` class and make sure that `.image-hidden` **don't have** `display: none;`.

Do similiar to `.image-shown`.

Then add transitions to `.image-shown` and `.image-hidden`

```
.image-shown { 
    /* ... */
    opacity: 1;
}

.image-hidden {
    /* ... */
    opacity: 0;
}

.image-shown, .image-hidden {
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s linear 0s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: opacity .5s linear 0s;
}
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r322X/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for css animation features. For example, add/change your css to:

```
.carousel-inner {
    /* We keep it position relative */
    position: relative;
    /* Change or remove these if you want */
    height: 30px;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px dashed;
}
.carousel-inner img {
    /* So that they go on top of each other */
    position: absolute;
    /* Transitions; we animate the opacity, but you can animate whatever you want */
    -webkit-transition: opacity 5s ease; /* 5 seconds */
    -moz-transition: opacity 5s ease;
    -ms-transition: opacity 5s ease;
    -o-transition: opacity 5s ease;
    transition: opacity 5s ease;
}
/* This is just for you, to tell the difference between the images (not necessary) */
img:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: white;
}
img:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: green;
}
.image-shown {
    /* Change this from
    display: block;
    to: */
    opacity: 1;
}
.image-hidden {
    /* Change this from
    display: none;
    to: */
    opacity: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mb9b6/

Notice how the image fades in to the next one. No changes are needed to the script, but if you make it `position: relative` for `carousel-inner` and `position: absolute` for the images, then you can remove the stuff with `z-index` as it would no longer be necessary. Only one image will be shown at a time anyway.

Note that this will only work in modern browsers. If you need to support older browsers, use jQuery's `fade` methods like so:

```
$('#button-next').on('click', function(){
  $('#big').css({'display':'none'});

  var currentActiveImage = $('.image-shown');
  var nextActiveImage = currentActiveImage.next();

  if (nextActiveImage.length == 0) {
    nextActiveImage = $('.carousel-inner img').first();
  }

  currentActiveImage.removeClass('image-shown').addClass('image-hidden').fadeOut();
  nextActiveImage.addClass('image-shown').removeClass('image-hidden').fadeIn();
  e.preventDefault()    
});
```

If you do that, then remove all css for `image-shown` and `image-hidden`; they become simple marker classes. Do similarly for the `prev` button.